# An evaluation about Gamma function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, gamma-function

$a,b>0$, we have the estimate:
$$C(b)^{-1}(a+1)^b\leq \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)}\leq C(b)(a+1)^b$$
Where $C(b)$ is a constant does not depend on $a$.

Actually, for $b\geq 1$, this can be easily proved by using the formulas $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$. But how to prove the case of $0<b<1$? Thanks very much.

Comment: The lower bound is wrong (when $a\to 0$). Otherwise, considering $a\to+\infty$ (using e.g. Stirling's formula) will do.

Comment: Now, I am trying to use the boundary of the function $$\frac{\Gamma (x+b)}{\Gamma(x)(x+1)^b}$$ to prove this

Comment: I ask my advisor, this is true need that $a\rightarrow \infty $